USB POS Printer loses connection suddenly
I have a Windows 10 PC which is up to date, connected to a POS printer by mean of USB cable.
The problem I am having is that I am printing normally in it, using Windows spool, and it works, until suddenly printer loses connection, causing the print queue to stay for ever.
To recover control, I need the printer to turn off and on, or reboot the PC. After that, all pending jobs are printed normally.
Driver is not the problem, I have uninstalled and install the driver again. I have cleaned the printing spool, I have changed cable, I have changed printer, and problem is not solved. The only thing I have not done is to reinstall Windows or changed the PC because these are the most complicated thing to do.
What else can I try?
Thanks
Jaime
